# AWS Lambda not importing LXML

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lxml, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the LXML module within AWS Lambda and having no luck. I downloaded LXML using the following command:

```
pip install lxml -t folder
```

To download it to my lambda function deployment package. I zipped the contents of my lambda function up as I have done with all other lambda functions, and uploaded it to AWS Lambda.

However no matter what I try I get this error when I run the function:

```
Unable to import module 'handler': /var/task/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf
```

When I run it locally, I don't have an issues, it is simply when I run in on Lambda where this issue arises.

Comment: lxml requires system level packages to be installed which must be done on an Amazon linux AMI and included in your lambda bundle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the same issue.

The link posted by [Raphaël Braud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3169644/rapha%C3%ABl-braud) was helpful and so was this one: 
https://nervous.io/python/aws/lambda/2016/02/17/scipy-pandas-lambda/

Using the two links I was able to successfully import lxml and other required packages. Here are the steps I followed:

- Launch an ec2 machine with Amazon Linux ami
- Run the following script to accumulate dependencies:

  ```
  set -e -o pipefail
  sudo yum -y upgrade
  sudo yum -y install gcc python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel

  virtualenv ~/env && cd ~/env && source bin/activate
  pip install lxml
  for dir in lib64/python2.7/site-packages \
       lib/python2.7/site-packages
  do
  if [ -d $dir ] ; then
     pushd $dir; zip -r ~/deps.zip .; popd
  fi
  done  
  mkdir -p local/lib
  cp /usr/lib64/ #list of required .so files
  local/lib/
  zip -r ~/deps.zip local/lib
  ```
- Create handler and worker files as specified in the [link](http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html). Sample file contents:

handler.py

```
import os
import subprocess


libdir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'local', 'lib')

def handler(event, context):
    command = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH={} python worker.py '.format(libdir)
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    print output

    return
```

worker.py:

```
import lxml

def sample_function( input_string = None):
    return "lxml import successful!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = sample_function()
    print result
```

- Add handler and worker to zip file.

Here is how the structure of the zip file looks after the above steps:

```
deps 
├── handler.py
├── worker.py 
├── local
│   └── lib
│       ├── libanl.so
│       ├── libBrokenLocale.so
|       ....
├── lxml
│   ├── builder.py
│   ├── builder.pyc
|       ....
├── <other python packages>
```

- Make sure you specify the correct handler name while creating the lambda function. In the above example, it would be- "handler.handler"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Extending on these answers, I found the following to work well.

The punchline here is having python compile lxml with static libs, and installing in the current directory rather than site-packages.

It also means you can write your python code as usual, without need for a distinct worker.py or fiddling with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
sudo yum -y install python36-devel python36-pip
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip-3.6 /usr/bin/pip3
mkdir lambda && cd lambda
STATIC_DEPS=true pip3 install -t . lxml
zip -r ~/deps.zip *
```

to take it to the next level, use serverless and docker to handle everything. here is a blog post demonstrating this:
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this using the [serverless](https://serverless.com/) framework and its built-in Docker feature.

Requirement: You have an AWS profile in your .aws folder that can be accessed.

First, install the serverless framework as described [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/getting-started/). You can then create a configuration file using the command `serverless create --template aws-python3 --name my-lambda`. It will create a serverless.yml file and a handler.py with a simple "hello" function. You can check if that works with a `sls deploy`. If that works, serverless is ready to be worked with.

Next, we'll need an additional plugin named ["serverless-python-requirements"](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) for bundling Python requirements. You can install it via `sls plugin install --name serverless-python-requirements`.

This plugin is where all the magic happens that we need to solve the missing lxml package. In the custom->pythonRequirements section you simply have to add the `dockerizePip: non-linux` property. Your serverless.yml file could look something like this:

```
service: producthunt-crawler

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  hello:
    # some handler that imports lxml
    handler: handler.hello

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    fileName: requirements.txt
    dockerizePip: non-linux

    # Omits tests, __pycache__, *.pyc etc from dependencies
    slim: true
```

This will run the bundling of python requirements inside a pre-configured docker container. After this, you can run `sls deploy` to see the magic happen and then `sls invoke -f my_function` to check that it works.

When you've used serverless to deploy and add the `dockerizePip: non-linux` option later, make sure to clean up your already built requirements with `sls requirements clean`. Otherwise, it just uses the already built stuff.

Comment: You need Docker installed to get this to work. Also good article about this: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/.

Comment: I ended up using serverless in the end *(even copying the packages serverless created, making a zip and uploading it didn't work for me)*

Comment: This is a great solution.  Here is an important caveat that had me spinning my wheels though:  If you've been running sls deploy prior to adding the `dockerizePip` option to your yaml, sls may continue to use cached version of your requirements!  This will cause the change to the yaml to have no effect!  Check your sls deploy output for something like `Using static cache of requirements...`, if it says that, you MUST nuke the referenced cached files before this solution will work.

Comment: @OliverHolmberg great comment! This is very important as most guys will of course find out this after they've compiled already.

Comment: This is by far much easier and faster solution to the problem!! Should be upvoted to the top.

Comment: This should be the only answer here, FULL STOP! .

Answer (score 4):

The lxml library is os dependent thus we need to have precompiled copy. Below are the steps.

1. Create a docker container.
   `docker run -it lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 bash`
2. Create a dir named 'lib'(anything you want) and Install lxml into it.
   `mkdir lib`
   `pip install lxml -t ./lib --no-deps`
3. Open another cmd and run
   `docker ps`
4. copy the `containerid`
5. Copy the files from container to host.
   `mkdir /home/libraries/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`
   `docker cp <containerid>:/var/task/lib /home/libraries/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`
6. Now you have lxml copy of files compiled from amazonlinux box, If you like to have lxml as Lambda layer.  Navigate to `/home/libraries/opt` and zip the folder named `python`.Name the zip as `opt`. Now you can attach the zip in your lambda as layer.
7. If you want lxml library inside lambda. Navigate to `/home/libraries/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` and copy the `lxml` folder in your lambda.

Comment: More info here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/

Comment: So the ZIP file that you upload to be a Layer should have the following structure in it?
  
* python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lxml  
* python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lxml-4.6.4.dist-info

Ugh, can't get the formatting to work.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on Mask's answer. In the case of installing lxml in particular, ***the libxslt and libxml2 libraries are already installed on the AMI that executes the AWS lambda. Therefore it is no need to start a subprocess with a different LD_LIBRARY_PATH as in that answer***, it is however necessary to run pip install lxml on an AMI image (it might be possible to cross-compile as well but I don't know how).

```
Launch an ec2 machine with Amazon Linux ami
Run the following script to accumulate dependencies:
set -e -o pipefail
sudo yum -y upgrade
sudo yum -y install gcc python-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel

virtualenv ~/env && cd ~/env && source bin/activate
pip install lxml
for dir in lib64/python2.7/site-packages \
    lib/python2.7/site-packages
do
    if [ -d $dir ] ; then
        pushd $dir; zip -r ~/deps.zip .; popd
    fi
done
```

Note that the last steps from Marks answer is left out. You can use lxml straight from the python file that contains the handler method.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda use a special version of Linux (as far as I can see).

Using "pip install a_package -t folder" is the good thing to do usually as it will help to package your dependencies within the archive that will be sent to Lambda, but the libraries, and especially the binary libraries have to be compatible with the version of OS and Python on lambda.

You could use the xml module included in Python : https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

If you really need lxml, this link gives some tricks on how to compile shared libraries for Lambda :
http://www.perrygeo.com/running-python-with-compiled-code-on-aws-lambda.html

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working by following the readme on [this](https://github.com/JFox/aws-lambda-lxml) page:

1. With docker installed, run this command (replacing `python3.8` with the version of python you are using for your lambda function, and `lxml` with the version of lxml you want to use)

   ```
   $ docker run -v $(pwd):/outputs -it lambci/lambda:build-python3.8 \
         pip install lxml -t /outputs/
   ```
2. This will create a folder called `lxml` in your working directory, and possibly some other folders which you can ignore. Move the `lxml` folder to the same directory as the `.py` file you are using as your lambda handler.
3. Zip up the `.py` file with the lxml folder, as well as any packages if you are using a virtualenv. I had a virtualenv and lxml already existed in my site-packages folder, so I had to delete it first. Here are the commands I ran (note that my virtualenv v-env folder was in the same directory as my `.py` file):

   ```
   FUNCTION_NAME="name_of_your_python_file"
   cd v-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages &&
   rm -rf lxml &&
   rm -rf lxml-4.5.1.dist-info &&
   zip -r9 ${OLDPWD}/${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip . &&
   cd ${OLDPWD} &&
   zip -g ${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip ${FUNCTION_NAME}.py && 
   zip -r9 ${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip lxml
   ```
4. If you don't have a virtualenv or any other dependencies, you can just run

   ```
   FUNCTION_NAME="name_of_your_python_file"
   zip -g ${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip ${FUNCTION_NAME}.py && 
   zip -r9 ${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip lxml
   ```
5. Upload ${FUNCTION_NAME}.zip to your lambda function and use as normal.

More on creating a .zip file for lambda with a virtualenv [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-venv)

Answer (score 0):

LXML is very sensitive with its running environment.

I fixed this issue by building the zip Lambda package in a **python:3.x-slim** container :

```
pip install --target=. lxml
zip -r lambda.zip lambda.py lxml
```

Image container version must be the same that the python engine version used in Lambda

Tested successfully with python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8

Answer (score -1):

You can find whl file for this and most other projects here;
https://pypi.org/project/lxml/#files

Comment: It's not immediately obvious how this answers the question, or improves upon e.g. [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450406/3025856). I can understand why it might be useful for people on this thread to know where to find the latest version of LXML files. But as it doesn't answer the question directly it should be posted as a comment.